# How do I loop through a java.io exception (502)?

Tags: java

I'm getting this error : java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL:

and it ends my program if the website has a bad gate, and its inconsistent on working or not. Is there any way I can force it to keep on retrying the website until it gets a response?

this is currently my code if it matters:

```
    URL webpage = null;
    URLConnection conn = null;
    try{
        webpage = new URL(websiteurl);
        conn=webpage.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF8");
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line = "";
        while(true){
            line = buffer.readLine();
            if(line!=null){
               System.out.println(line);
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

nevermind solved it by recalling my method in the catch and adding in a pause between each call : this is what it is now

```
URL webpage = null;
            URLConnection conn = null;
            try{
                webpage = new URL(website);
                
                conn=webpage.openConnection();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF8");
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
                String line = "";
                while(true){
                    line = buffer.readLine();
                    if(line!=null){
                       System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                 try
            {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
                findCreationDate(name);
            }
```

Comment: *"keep on retrying the website until it gets a response"* - The 502 error is a response. Since it's a 5xx response, it indicates a server-side error, usually meaning the request should not be repeated because you'll just get the same error again. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors

Comment: how do i keep on retrying the website though, it gives me an error in my console and my program stops running

Comment: The only line in your catch block is `e.printStackTrace();`.  You need to make a good faith attempt first, and then we can help you where you get stuck.  Right now we can't help you because we can't see how you've tried to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: What I'm telling you is that even if you do keep retrying, it probably isn't going to help, because you will probably get the same error every time you retry. If it's a website you control, you need to fix it on the server side, otherwise contact whoever is responsible for it to let them know about the error and ask what you should do.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong the only solution i have is to recursively call my method but that wouldn't work if it ends my program instantly :(

edit : nevermind i fixed it by recursively calling it till it forced it to respond...

Comment: @tahmim are you sure this ends your program instantly?  Is this code in the main method?  Because when Java reaches the end of the program, it terminates it.  So if you have nothing after this, it stands to reason your program would terminate.  A recursive call is a good solution, could you post that code so we know what we're dealing with?

Comment: You don't need, and probably don't want, to use recursion.  Just put the request attempt in a loop, wrapped in a try/catch that is inside the loop. At some point, you can decide to give up retrying by calling `break` to exit out of the loop.  If you're going to retry even upon getting a 502, i would suggest that you use a progressive back-off scheme, where you try again right away, and then wait longer and longer between retries: 5 sec, 15 sec, 1 min, 5 min, etc.

Comment: @tahmim Sounds like you've fixed your problem.  Nice job!  Please consider posting an answer here so others can benefit from this post.

Comment: @Steve yeah i should probably wait between calls a bit, and I think recursion is the best way im writing my program since im going through a list and calling a website to get information from each object in my list

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong will do

Comment: @tahmim I just noticed you put the answer in the question.  You should add it as an answer instead, to make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

solved it by recalling my method in the catch and adding in a pause between each call : this is what it is now

```
URL webpage = null;
            URLConnection conn = null;
            try{
                webpage = new URL(website);
                
                conn=webpage.openConnection();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF8");
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
                String line = "";
                while(true){
                    line = buffer.readLine();
                    if(line!=null){
                       System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                 try
            {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
                findCreationDate(name);
            }
```